# Erro no eclipse de não reconhecimento dos modificadores static e default

Tags: java

Galera o eclipse não reconhece quando quero criar uma classe dentro de uma interface com modificadores static e default.
obs: Já tenho a jdk do JAVA 8 instalada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já, muito obrigado.
Att,
Thiago Marques.

Comment: Qual é o erro que o eclipse diz que tem?

Comment: Qual é a versão do eclipse?

Comment: Não da erro, só diz pra excluir a expressão default que ele não reconhece.A versão do eclipse é  Kepler Service Release 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá, siga os seguintes passos:

1 - Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler: Checa se tá com o java 8 no Compiler compliance level.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs: Checa se você tem a biblioteca setada para o java 8:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3 - Depois de ajustar tudo, dá um clean no projeto: Project > Clean... > Clean all projects

Espero ter ajudado ^^

Comment: Não aparece 1.8, vai até 1.7, mas ja tenho a jdk java 8, como faço pra habilitar e aparecer 1.8?

Comment: Você precisa ter o eclipse Luna no mínimo, versões anteriores não suportam o java 8.

Comment: sou meio ruim pra essas paradas, não sou da área de T.I, é só baixar o luna em qual versão?

Comment: Faz o seguinte, verifica qual a tua versão primeiro: Help > About Eclipse. Manda o print ou cola o texto que for exibido.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2013.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://eclipse.org/

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation http://apache.org/

Comment: como mando screen shot? n aparece aqui

Comment: Pronto, então o problema é porque você tá usando o eclipse Kepler. Baixa o eclipse Neon (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/neonr) e abre teu projeto nele. Aí vai aparecer o java 8 no compiler.

Comment: Vou baixar, obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou !, obrigado.

Comment: Aeww! De nada ^^